# How to write to excel using python3?

Tags: excel, python-3.x

How to write to excel using python3

How to write 2 values to first columnA, other 2 values to column B and other 2 to column c like that until the line ends

```
  listoflist=[["data1$","data2$"],["content1","content2"],["first","second"]]

   for i,string in enumerate(listoflist):
          for j in string:
            replaced = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9/.' ]+", '', j)
            print(replaced)
             column_count = 2
def excel_file():

     new_row_data =[["heading"],[replaced]]
     workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Input.xlsx')
     workbook.close()

      wb = load_workbook("Input.xlsx")
      ws = wb.worksheets[0]

      for row_data in new_row_data:
               ws.append(row_data)

      wb.save("table.xlsx") 
      print("Please Open the Excel File")


excel_file()
```

Expected Output: want output in excel file

```
  Column A      Column B        Column c
  data1         content1        first
  data2         content2        second
```

Comment: I believe there is a function in the pandas library that makes opening excel easy.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html

Comment: thank you but how can i split values as 2 to write

Comment: I'm not sure but you can check out http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-excel-writer